# Как сделать кнопку "play" для видео, как на макете?

Tags: html5

Здравствуйте! Как можно сделать такую кнопку, как на этом макете?
http://uploads.ru/XfCgH.png

`<div class="video-play">
        <video width="635" height="430" controls poster="img/video-poster.jpg">
                <source src="video/moon.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>`

В результате у меня показываются настройки по умолчанию заданные controls.
http://uploads.ru/8Lcyf.png

А мне надо по-другому. Вообщем, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться как привести все это в нужный вид, и чтобы проигрывалось при нажатии иконки плей, скрыв панель control.

Comment: если без скриншотов в вопросе никак не обойтись. то по возможности включайте минимально возможный по размеру скриншот в сам вопрос а не ссылу на него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по макету, нужно чтоб была заглушка, и по нажатию на неё запускать уже само видео, соответственно можно сделать поверх видео заглушку по нажатию на которую скрывать её и запускать видео.

Comment: Это решается с помощью яваскрипт, да? нет какого-нибудь плагина, не знаете?  Нашел такое вот решение на кодепен: http://codepen.io/stanislas-prime/pen/akrpD           Бьюсь на яваскрипт кодом. И спасибо за ответ, без вас бы я не узнал, что это дело называется заглушкой)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh924823(v=vs.85).aspx тут есть скрипт где по нажатию на ту или иную кнопку можно запускать или останавливать видео, переделайте под ваши нужды. Думаю этого будит достаточно.

Comment: Спасибо большое!Щас попробуем...