# Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать кнопку play на видео, так как на скрине?

Tags: javascript, css

Я думал через btn, и потом через события, но такой вариант не очень нравится...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать кнопку "play" для видео, как на макете?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/591137/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-play-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: @xydope я не очень в этой теме, но в вопросе, который вы приводите так себе ответ

Comment: @Dmitry что значит "так себе"? Там дан нормальный ответ, сделать поверх видео блок, по нажатию на который будет воспроизводиться видео. Если вас это не устраивает, уточните, как вы представляете решение.

Comment: @xydope вы весь комментарий прочитали? Я не силен в этой теме. А ответ, возможно, может быть детальнее, развернутее.